# Set a value with a key to a specific date

Tags: android, calendar

Can I set a value (e.g. boolean) in a Calender date using a key and later retrieve it? Right now I am maintaining a database for this.
I am keeping track of tasks (say 100 tasks) which occur every month. To know whether the task was completed or not on a specific month, I want to set a value with a key in the task's date and later retrieve it. Is it possible?

Comment: Thats all? More info. From what I got, you can use `HashMap` for that.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean storing it in a "local" variable ?

You may try `using java.util.Map;` with the methods :

```
V put(K key,
    V value);
```

then, to look for results :

```
for (Map.Entry<Key,Value> data : content.entrySet() ) { //Replace Value with your stored data type
//Manage your stored stuff here

}
```

More info here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: I am dealing with a large amount of data. So, I can't use maps. Moreover, I want to retrieve the value later (after app restarts). Right now I am using Database for this.

Comment: how about storing the map into SharedPreferences ? :)

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question, you want to perform some actions at scheduled date and are looking for a way to know if the current date is exactly the date when your scheduled action should start.

You have to store the scheduled date, and compare the date in this way

e.g

```
Calendar currentDate = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
boolean startTask=currentDate.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == storedDateToCompare.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
if(startTask){
   //do something
}
```

To store the Calendar date, you have various options, you could also store the date as String in your database and parse the date to a Calendar object when you have to perform the checks.

More info about Calendar [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Comment: I don't want to store Calender date. Instead, I want to store a boolean value in a Calender date.

Comment: You cannot. See Calendar class